# Converting date with time in a column to week in character in R

Tags: r, datetime, data-conversion, week-number

I have data with date information including time and I'd like to convert them to a `week` of the `year` in character format. For example for the following data

```
Case     Time
 1   2020-01-12 11:28:46
 2   2020-01-22 10:17:24
```

I'd like to have a column with values such as `January 6th, 2020` instead of `2020-w02` that can be produced by the `date2week` package. So, for this data the favourite outcome will be like:

```
Case     Time              time_by_day2week   favorite_time
 1   2020-01-12 11:28:46      2020-w02       January 6th, 2020
 2   2020-01-22 10:17:24      2020-w04       January 20th, 2020
```

So, the favorite_time column mentions the `first day (Monday)` of that week.

It would be much appreciated if someone can help.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it from `aweek` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can floor the `Date` object with `floor_date` and then use `format`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time), 
           favorite_time =   format(floor_date(Time, "weeks",
                 week_start = 1), "%B %dth, %Y"))
#  Case                Time      favorite_time
#1    1 2020-01-12 11:28:46 January 06th, 2020
#2    2 2020-01-22 10:17:24 January 20th, 2020
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Case = 1:2, Time = c("2020-01-12 11:28:46", 
"2020-01-22 10:17:24"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: would the `as.Date` function report the Monday of each week as the day?